# Making POST request with http client

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpclient

I am trying to make http web request  with http client , passing `Dictionary<string,object>` as the parameters have image byte array

But I can't encode the content with FormUrlEncodedContent as its giving me

"  cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>`"

is there any other recommended method to pass many parameters in different types ( string, bytearray )

here is a snippet of my code !

```
   var Imagesvalues = new Dictionary<string, object>
{


   { "propertyid", newpropertyID },
    { "image", imageArray },
                { "featured", isFeatured }

                };


                var finalcontent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Imagesvalues);



                response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost/modon/addimage", finalcontent);
                featuresindex = featuresindex + 1;
```

Comment: Make a `Dictionary<string, string>`instead.

Comment: I already solved using the normal http web request method,

Answer (score 0):

**PostAsync** is a short way for post requests with known types.

In order to send specific types as dictionary of string with object -
convert it to Json and use **HttpWebRequest** :

```
        var values = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
        values.Add("par1", "0V8");
        values.Add("par2", "67");
        values.Add("variableValues", kvp);

        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
        //This gives you the byte array.

        var dataToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.ContentLength = dataToSend.Length;
        req.Method = "POST";
```